# How To Setting NAT Access Point via CLI? Orange Pi

Tags: wifi, access-point

I want to set up an access point using NAT via CLI. When I use 'orangepi-config' settings, I can't figure out the settings via CLI.

How to Configure NAT Access Point Using CLI?

Note:

OS : Orange Pi Bionic with Linux 4.9.170-sun50iw9

I've done it according to the procedure, like

1. Disable systemd-resolved

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved

   sudo rm -v /etc/resolv.conf

   echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
   ```
2. Install DNSMASQ

   `sudo apt install dnsmasq -y`
3. DHCP Settings

   `sudo mv -v /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf.bk`

   `sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf`

   ```
   listen-address=172.24.1.1

   bind-interfaces

   server=8.8.8.8

   domain-needed

   bogus-priv

   dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h


   sudo rfkill unblock wlan

   sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
   ```
4. Port Forwarding

   `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

   ```
   kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
   vm.swappiness=100
   ```
5. IPTABLES

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

   iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

   iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
   ```
6. Hostapd

   `sudo nano /etc/hostapd.conf`

   ```
   # orangepi hostapd configuration example
   #
   # nl80211 mode
   #

   ssid=OrangePi
   interface=wlan0
   hw_mode=g
   channel=40
   #bridge=br0
   driver=nl80211

   logger_syslog=0
   logger_syslog_level=0
   wmm_enabled=1
   wpa=2
   preamble=1

   wpa_psk=66eb31d2b48d19ba216f2e50c6831ee11be98e2fa3a8075e30b866f4a5ccda27
   wpa_passphrase=12345678
   wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   wpa_pairwise=TKIP
   rsn_pairwise=CCMP
   auth_algs=1
   macaddr_acl=0

   ## IEEE 802.11n
   ieee80211n=1
   ht_capab=[SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][HT40+]
   country_code=US
   ieee80211d=1
   ## IEEE 802.11n

   ## IEEE 802.11a
   hw_mode=a
   ## IEEE 802.11a

   ## IEEE 802.11ac
   ieee80211ac=1
   vht_capab=
   vht_oper_chwidth=1
   vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
   ## IEEE 802.11ac

   # controlling enabled
   ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
   ctrl_interface_group=0
   ```

But, it's **FAILED**

Comment: According to what procedure? You wrote iptables commands in `sysctl.conf`, that won't work anyways. And it would be nice to know what failed? System crash? Hanging? no forwarding?

Comment: @stoney Oh, I'm sorry. That's a different process. I didn't write iptables at ```systcl```, I revised them. The AP just doesn't run, doesn't show the SSID.